Precipitation on an outer exomoon heated by tidal heating
Following this question, how would rain behave on an outer system habitable moon (>5AU from a sun-like star) heated by tidal-heating? According to this page, an outer planet or moon with low insolation but monoclime habitable temperatures will have very slow winds and not much rainfall, but the air itself will be saturated with moisture (close to 100% relative humidity).
Does this mean that even on a moon with >80% surface ocean coverage, the climate on the land will be arid (like foggy deserts in western Peru), or will there be enough precipitation to have a mostly global humid climate (oceanic for a temperate climate, tropical rainforest for a hot climate, according to the Köppen classifications)?

Saturn's moon Titan has precipitation - though of methane. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)

The conditions the OP describes are very similar to Jupiter and Europa.  Europa is thought to have a water ocean beneath a relatively smooth icy crust, with a thin oxygen atmosphere.  The liquid water ocean is thought to remain as a liquid due to tidal heating.
However, tidal heating has also caused the conditions on Io, which is very volcanically active, and has a very low water content, probably because it all boiled off and escaped due to the low molecular weight of gases retained.  So, there is probably a fine line between "all the water will boil off" and "the surface water will be frozen".  To have a relatively dense atmosphere in which weather can occur, the moon will need to be large enough to retain atmospheric gases.
So, let us assume that we have a moon somewhere between Io and Europa, with a water content covering (very approximately) 50% of the surface area, which is large enough that the water vapour won't escape.
In the solar heating scenario that we are familiar with on Earth, we get the greatest amount of insolation around the equator, leading to familiar atmospheric circulation.  However, in a tidal heating scenario, insolation will be an insignificant part of the forces driving the climate.
So, on a tidally heated world, the energy that drives the climate will come from the ground.  However, the ground won't be a uniform temperature, since the liquifaction of the world's core will lead to columns of hotter and cooler material rising and falling, which will in turn result in hot spots and cool spots on the surface.  These hot and cool spots won't necessarily be oriented equatorially, as can be seen from images of Io, where volcanoes occur at all latitudes.
With an atmosphere and hydrosphere, these geological hot spots will result in geothermally heated air and water.  Since hot air and water will rise, and hot water will evaporate more rapidly, we can expect that cooler air will be drawn toward the hot spots, will rise and cool, and form clouds above and around the hot spots as the air cools.  As the clouds cool further as they travel outward from the thermal plumes, the water they carry will condense and be precipitated as rain.  Due to chaotic interactions between different thermal plumes, we can expect that winds will be light to moderate but variable in direction and rainfall won't be constant.
The climate being humid or dry will depend upon the water content, the amount of tidal heating, and quite likely the composition of the world's core.  The lower the melting point of the geosphere, the lower its molten viscosity and the greater the tidal heating, the more active the world's volcanism will be, and the greater the difference in temperature between the hot and cool spots.  The greater the temperature differences, the more likely the hot areas are to be humid and the cold areas are to be dry and even frozen.
However, we can expect the hot areas to be more humid and the cold areas to be less humid, though the volcanism that may be expected to be associated with hot spots may result in volcanic cones that will displace water, reducing the humidity of the hot spots.
TL,DR: We can expect humid hot spots with clouds migrating outward from them, rainfall from the clouds as they cool, and cold spots that will be drier and potentially frozen.
The Koppen climate would necessarily be variants on a theme of "f", since there would be no seasons, and temperature may range from tropical (A) to polar (F), with little to no dry (B) climatic zones.  However, Koppen climatic classification is a system designed for solar-heated terrestrial climates, and not tidally-heated exomoons.

Also a very good answer. I can’t help but notice though that you mentioned assuming the world had ~50% surface ocean coverage. Would 80% ocean coverage (think like Laythe from KSP) still be possible? I suppose that would depend on atmospheric density, escape velocity etc. More suited for my previous question.

@casualworldbuilder I did say "very approximately" 50%.  That could cover anything from 10% to 90% water coverage.  With such an active geology, I would expect shallow seas.

Ah okay, apologies for the confusion. And yes, shallower seas than Earth for the most part would be likely.

If I may add, Coriolis forces would align ocean currents and winds even though the motors for such are spread "randomly". Similar to the Antarctic Circumpolar Current and passage winds. This could build up energy over time and concentrate forces. And bring more separation between zones.

I'm inclined to think, because altitudinal cooling will be a thing, (in fact more of a thing since, for all intents and purposes, all the heat will be from the ground up) that precipitation will be quite high. Rain all day, everyday, everywhere, a steady monotonous vertical downpour assuming it is a monoclimate. With the possibility of a totally arid surface being continuously hammered by dry lightning with the rain evaporating before it made it to the ground, if the heat flux is high enough.
However on a geologically active world I would expect to see sharp differences in the local rate of heat migration, primarily in line with differences in crustal thickness but with hotspots etc... as well. This would create a far more dynamic weather environment with high and low pressure cells, most of which will be effectively permanent, and wind systems moving heat and moisture around between areas of evaporation and condensation. Still a LOT of rain, like peak monsoon but constant in cooler areas, and with steaming valley bottoms where the ground is hottest.

So I have essentially created a global Mawsynram without the dry season lol

Isn't altitudinal cooling also a thing on Earth? Yet we don't have constant downpours(not worldwide, and even then it is dependent more on humidity), so why does it result in constant rain here?

@Bubbles I am not so sure myself but I think it’s because the heat is generated from the ground up rather than by the sun and is more uniform all over the moon

@bubbles In certain layers of the atmosphere yes but the thermosphere experiences increasing temperature with altitude due to incoming solar radiation putting an effective limit on how cold clouds can get, that won't happen on a world where insolation is effectively nil. On a monocline world evaporation is constant across the surface and there are no air currents to move the water around, remove it from some areas and concentrate it in others. A monocline world with that much water available would experience constant global rainfall as the water goes up and down without moving geographically.

This is going to depend on some other factors, but the boring answer is you can decide, because planets are strange and bizarre and the tiniest little changes can lead to enormous effects. My followup question would be to ask if your planet is tidally locked.
So a primer, rain is affected by temperature differential and pressure. Eventually, if vapour is permitted to form, it will reach a breaking point. 100% Humidity just means it's always breaking that point, fog and condensation galore. Humidity levels are dependent on atmospheric composition. If you had a thicker atmosphere, you might be able to hold more moisture in it, and have a lower relative humidity.
Monoclime worlds, from the source you've given, are of a similar temperature due to atmospheric thickness. This is... somewhat mistaken, and it covers it very briefly, but the actual reason is atmospheric circulation, not thickness. A thick atmosphere is more likely to trap heat, but dispersing it evenly is a different problem.
As hot air rises and cools, due to the Coriolis effect, tropical air moves polewards but is diverted by the rotation until it forms a front or jet stream. These (at least on Earth) split rather nicely latitudinally into 3 cells per hemisphere.

This circulation is important, because the tropical Hadley Cell contains the most heat and is the most stable. It's theorised that if Earth spun about 5 times slower, then this Cell would reach all the way to the poles and in fact we would likely get a far more moderated climate overall.
Conversely, the faster a planet spins, the more segregated its heat is likely to be latitudinally.
Now why does all this matter? Well, this is what makes rain, on the macro scale. The wettest regions on Earth are where low-pressure belts usually form, which is primarily from atmospheric circulation. It's why we have a wet equator but dry 30 degree latitudes, and then wet 60 degree latitudes. Check out those arrows, that's where vapour will be carried.
Now there are two caveats to consider with your planet, because all this is well and good if you have a temperature differential from equator to pole in the first place, and if your planet spins and isn't tidally locked.
Basically, you want high pressure areas where water can evaporate, and then low pressure areas where that water rains back down. That's it! Congratulations, you have rain!
Well... here's where it gets tricky. Theoretically, you should have less latitudinal temperature variation, because solar insolation is lower. However, tidal heating is what is causing your temperature differential.
If your planet turns, even a little bit, then the entire equator is going to get far, far more heat, because the gravitational energy is going to pull hardest on the closest part of the planet. This is going to give you a temperature gradient same as Earth.
If your planet is tidally locked, then you're in the same boat as Slow Earth, because your orbit will still have a slight eccentricity, and the planet will stretch and squash as it orbits, with the highest energy concentrated into a single pole, which will then flood all the way to the other pole, with no rotation to divert it.
I'd recommend looking further into Worldbuilding Pasta's blog posts for more information, they're very insightful.
TLDR: I don't see any reason why your planet wouldn't have high winds if it had a thick atmosphere. Titan is a good example for you to look at, it has a thick greenhouse-ridden atmosphere, volcanism, and yet it still rains (not water, methane). Temperature difference and pressure is everything.
https://worldbuildingpasta.blogspot.com/2023/06/climate-explorations-day-length.html - Climate Exploration - Changes in Day Length
https://worldbuildingpasta.blogspot.com/2020/12/an-apple-pie-from-scratch-part-ivd.html - Tidally-Locked Planets

My world is a moon and it’s tidally-locked to a gas giant (not the star). It has low insolation (>5AU from sun-like star) and climate is driven primarily by tidal heating. It has a somewhat thick atmosphere comprised of nitrogen, carbon dioxide, methane and various volcanic gases. Oxygen is present but not enough to breathe (about Mount Everest levels).

I wouldn't expect monocline climate from internal heating.
Heat getting from the core to the surface experiences a positive feedback effect: more heat makes softer rocks makes more ability for magma to force its way in makes more heat.  The result is lots of the heat will be focused in a smallish number of unpredictable places.  And this is indeed what we see on Io: not a uniformly hot ground but a scattering of discrete volcanos.
That's enough to produce convection winds.  Picture a pot of water boiling on a stove: that's a uniform fluid heated unevenly from below -- same idea.
And with convection winds, there will be rain.  Wherever hot humid air cools below its dew point.
What you won't get is big consistent cells and entire regions with the same prevailing wind.  Prevailing winds at ground level will blow approximately toward the nearest active volcano.
Probably also won't get giant storms like you have on Earth.  Those need to build strength over a consistent temperature gradient, and this moon will be too chopped up.  But there will be places where little storms are very common, which can easily produce the same level of precipitation.
